# Issue Class was explicitly imported, but it was not found on the classpath. We'll try to import it anyway

Tags: enunciate

I trying to import model classes into enunciate docs but I'm getting the following in  the Maven log:

```
Class com.mycompany.model.MyClass was explicitly imported, but it was not found on the classpath. We'll try to import it anyway.
```

I'm trying to include the Request and Response classes in my enunciate generated docs. However all I'm getting is the following:

```
POST
Request             Body
element:            (custom)
media types:        application/json

(no documentation provided)

Response            Body
element:            (custom)
media types:        application/json

(no documentation provided)
```

enunciate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enunciate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.27.xsd">
    <api-import pattern="com.mycompany.model.*" />
    <api-import pattern="com.mycompany.model.MyClass" />
    <api-classes>
        <include pattern="com.mycompany.common.imrest.model.*"/>
        <include pattern="com.mycompany.model.MyClass"/>
    </api-classes>
</enunciate>
```

pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Also, a second question. Is there a way to include sample JSON request and responses in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate scans your classpath, importing any classes you've configured to be imported. But it didn't find that class during its scan. Have you confirmed that you have a dependency on the jar that contains the `com.mycompany.model.MyClass` class?

Re: JSON examples: If `jackson-xc.jar` is on your classpath, Enunciate will generate the example JSON by default. Otherwise, you can force the example json:

```
 <enunciate ...>
   ...
   <modules>
     <docs forceExampleJson="true"/>
   </modules>
 </enunciate>
```